# Changing the thickness of a drawn line on JPanel with a ChangeListener on JSlider

Tags: java, swing

I have a JSlider that specifies the thickness of a line drawn on a JPanel. I added a ChangeListener to it, so when the slider is changed, it should also change the thickness of the line. But when I do that, the thickness doesn't change and instead, I'm given a faded out line. When I don't have the ChangeListener, the initial color is a purple line. I don't understand what's going on.

This is in my main GUI class, it includes the JSlider and the ChangeListener:

```
    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 20, 1);

    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);

    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(final ChangeEvent theEvent) {
            final int stroke = slider.getValue();
            myDrawPanel.setStroke(stroke);
            myDrawPanel.repaint();
        }
    });
```

And this is in another class where the line is being drawn:

```
public void setStroke(final int theStroke) {
    myStroke = theStroke;
}

public void paintComponent(final Graphics theGraphics) {
    super.paintComponent(theGraphics);
    final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) theGraphics;

    // for better graphics display
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2d.setPaint(new Color(51, 0, 111));
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(myStroke));

    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(myX, myY, myXEnd, myYEnd));

    for (Line2D l : myLines) {
        g2d.draw(l);
    } 
}
```

And this is the outcome: [image: 1]

And this is what the line originally looked like when I hardcoded a line thickness number in my paintComponent method:[image: 2]]

Comment: Are you actually changing the value of `myStroke` when you use `setStroke`?

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I forgot to include my setStroke method in my post, it's above my paintComponent method. I'll reedit my post.

Comment: Based on the snippets it should work. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I agree it looks like it should work. What  I would suggest doing, is adding a print statement to see what value you are actually getting for myStroke when you use your paint components.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work okay for me, I guess the problem is somewhere else in the code you're not showing us

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ControlPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ControlPane extends JPanel {

        public ControlPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            DrawPane pane = new DrawPane();
            add(pane);

            JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 20, 1);
            add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    pane.setStroke(slider.getValue());
                }
            });
            slider.setValue(1);
        }

    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        private int myStroke = 1;

        public DrawPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public void setStroke(int myStroke) {
            this.myStroke = myStroke;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(myStroke));
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: So I tried implementing your code into mine because I saw small differences between the two and figured maybe things I'm missing are causing the problem. But I'm still having the same issue. Now I'm thinking something else is causing it, but I don't know what. And I have two long classes.

Comment: Break the problem down to its smallest demonstrable level, removing anything which isn't directly related to the problem